# c project compile error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

ok,all my file like this

sendmail.h has some fucntion declared and some constant in this file

```
#define STMP_SERVER "smtp.exmail.qq.com"
#define LOGIN_NAME "secbot@test.com"
#define LOGIN_PASSOWRD "123456"
#define MAIL_TO "root@test.com"


char* get_local_addr(char* buf, size_t len);

int base64_encode(unsigned char *buf, int nLen, char *pOutBuf, int nBufSize);

void sendemail(char *smtpServer, char *serveruser, char *serverpassword, char *serverip);

int open_socket(struct sockaddr *addr);
```

sendmail.c has some function like sendmail.h function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stddef.h>

..............
```

test.c is main function

```
#include "sendmail.h"


#define SERVERNAME "root"
#define SERVERPASSWORD "123456"


int main()
{   
    sendemail(STMP_SERVER, SERVERNAME, SERVERPASSWORD,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

but compile error and say this

```
[root@ops test]# gcc -o test test.c 
In file included from test.c:1:
sendmail.h:10: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
sendmail.h:16: warning: ‘struct sockaddr’ declared inside parameter list
sendmail.h:16: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:10: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:10: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:10: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Comment: a) Use proper capitalization b) Include the _important_ and _relevant_ code c) It means you declared the same function (same name) multiple times.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't have the preprocessor include `*.c` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop using something like `#include "sendmail.c"` in `a.c`
2. Create a *header file* that contains *declarations* of functions in `sendmail.c`
3. `#include` the *header file* from `a.c`

Comment: 1.i user sedmail.h 2.a.c user #include sendmail.h but like this test.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `sendemail'

Comment: Link all needed files.

Comment: see the quetion,i modify it

Comment: Move these `#include`s in `sendmail.c` to `sendmail.h`.

Comment: yes i try do that,but they say /tmp/ccK66kVq.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `sendemail'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Try `gcc -o test test.c sendmail.c`